# jetty repositories for Debian lenny 5.0?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

This is my current sources.list, and I wish to install libjetty-java, libjetty-extra-java, and jetty, in that order. However, the packages are not found, and I resorted to downlaoding the debs from `http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/deb/` and fetching the dependencies viz. libslf4j-java libservlet2.5-java manually.

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian    lenny           main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org          lenny/updates   main contrib non-free

deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian    lenny       main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian/   lenny       main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/         lenny/updates   main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/     lenny/updates   main contrib non-free
```

My question is, is there a Debian repository for jetty? If not, will the above method be problematic in the long run? I ask, because I won't be eligible for automatic upgrades and the machine will be a production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jetty is in the Debian repositories](http://packages.debian.org/jetty), but at the moment only in the [testing](http://www.debian.org/releases/testing/) distribution, not in the [stable](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/) distribution which is what you have.

It looks like jetty doesn't have many dependencies that are not in lenny (stable), so a viable option is to keep your lenny system, but install a few binary packages from squeeze (testing). This is viable only if the testing packages don't depend on having recent (post-stable) versions of libraries. In particular, native executables are usually out since they require upgrading the the C library.

Add squeeze repositories to your sources by putting these lines in a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/squeeze.list`:

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
```

Then you'll be able to install packages from squeeze. But don't stop there, otherwise the next time you run `apt-get upgrade`, your system will become (almost) all-testing.

Create a file [`/etc/apt/preferences`](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) containing the following lines:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,a=testing
Pin-Priority: 200
```

Then packages from testing have a priority of 200, which is less than the default (500). So a package from testing will be installed only if there is no package with the same name in stable.